# Swift - How to enable landscape in full screen video?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, youtube, landscape-portrait

I am working on an iPhone(Swift) app and I have a WebView which loads a Youtube video and I would like to allow **landscape mode only when the video is full screen.** My whole app is portrait and rotation is disabled when the video is not playing in full screen. I don't want the user to be able to rotate the app to landscape when the youtube video is not in full screen, only when the video is playing in full screen.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`supportedInterfaceOrientations` was not such a reliable solution in my case as well. What I did was getting current view controller in app delegate `application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow` method and checked if that controller was a view controller that supported all orientations so its return value was calculated based on this condition

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> Int {

    if let currentVC = getCurrentViewController(self.window?.rootViewController){

        //VideoVC is the name of your class that should support landscape
        if currentVC is VideoVC{

            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
        }
    }
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
}

func getCurrentViewController(viewController:UIViewController?)-> UIViewController?{

     if let tabBarController = viewController as? UITabBarController{

        return getCurrentViewController(tabBarController.selectedViewController)
    }

    if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController{
        return getCurrentViewController(navigationController.visibleViewController)
    }

    if let viewController = viewController?.presentedViewController {

        return getCurrentViewController(viewController)

    }else{

        return viewController
    }
}
```

Comment: should I put this in my AppDelegate or in my viewController?

Comment: thanks. there's only one error now, please check:
http://postimg.org/image/5rntzarzz/

Comment: Fixed now, check it again

Comment: thanks again. No errors this time, but the app crashes when I load the app:
http://postimg.org/image/yqwd7jvw7/

Comment: no errors and crashes this time, but when i open the youtube video, i can't rotate it to landscape

Comment: Have you removed supportedInterfaceOrientations from test VC ?

Comment: yes. I did and only portrait mode is selected in the project settings.

Comment: Thats the problem, select all modes in project settings

Comment: yes I did. Now everything is in portrait and cannot be rotated but the video can't be rotated either unfortunately

Comment: here's my project, just click on test on the tab bar to see the video:
http://www.filedropper.com/motivateme

Comment: @MartonZeisler found the problem, didn't know that you were using tabbarcontroller, check the edited answer once more

Comment: yes it's better now. But I only want the user to be able to rotate to landscape if the video is playing. Right now I can rotate the screen even when I didn't even start watching the video. The screen should only be allowed to rotated when the webview's video is playing full screen. Once i close the video I shouldn't be able to rotate the screen to landscape.
http://postimg.org/image/q4hxrcd4f/

Comment: Any luck with making rotation video-only?

Comment: any luck guys? I have the same issue ... :(

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem recently and using [Zell B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422333/zell-b)'s answer, here is a Swift 5 version that will detect an AVPlayer and update the orientation settings.

Just copy and paste the below code into your AppDelegate (no editing necessary):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    if let currentVC = getCurrentViewController(self.window?.rootViewController), currentVC is AVPlayerViewController {
        return .allButUpsideDown
    }
    return .portrait
}

func getCurrentViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {

    if let tabBarController = viewController as? UITabBarController {
        return getCurrentViewController(tabBarController.selectedViewController)
    }

    if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController{
        return getCurrentViewController(navigationController.visibleViewController)
    }

    if let viewController = viewController?.presentedViewController {
        return getCurrentViewController(viewController)
    }
    
    return viewController
}
```