# How to play the video in landscape mode by default in AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avplayer

```
- (void)playMethod
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://www.rmp- 
    streaming.com/media///bbb-360p.mp4"];
    player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];

    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(15,50,345,300);
    controller.player = player;
    controller.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
    player.closedCaptionDisplayEnabled = NO;

    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button1 addTarget:self
                action:@selector(backMethod)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button1 setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     button1.frame = CGRectMake(50.0, CGRectGetMinY(controller.view.frame)+10, 160.0, 40.0);
    button1.tag = 1001;
    [self.view addSubview:button1];
    [controller.view  bringSubviewToFront:button1];
    [player pause];
    [player play];
    }
```

I want to play the video in landscape mode currently, its getting played in portrait mode. I want when the playMethod is called it should open the video in landscape mode only.

Comment: you have to forcely change the orientation of the device. As now your device is in landscape then video always play me landscape.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force landscape mode in AVPlayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519938/how-to-force-landscape-mode-in-avplayer)

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519938/how-to-force-landscape-mode-in-avplayer

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom class which is inherited from AVPlayerViewController and use this instead of base AVPlayerViewController

```
import AVKit

class CustomAVPlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController {

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .landscapeLeft
    }
}
```